# Probability of several consecutive drawn random samples of a standard normal distribution exceeding a certain value

Tags: normal-distribution, sample

I have trouble figuring out the following:

I have a standard normal distribution (µ = 0, σ² = 1) and now draw n random independent samples.

Lets assume the following: n = 3

What is the chance, that the sum of those samples is >0?

What is the chance, that the sum of those samples is >1?

What is the chance, that the sum of those samples is >3?

Comment: Seems to be a textbook problem. Please share your thoughts so far. If none: Maybe start by finding the distribution of $T = X_1+X_2+X_3.$

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried a scripted approximation as well and you are also right, I thought that this is probably a textbook problem, but I was still unable to find a satisfying - non approximation - answer. Therefore I thought maybe someone here can point me into the right direction.

Comment: A very great many posts on this site show how to answer such questions: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+normal+-truncated.

Comment: See my previous hint. $E(T)= E(X_1 + X_2 + X_3) = ?$ Assuming independence $Var(T)= Var(X_1 + X_2 + X_3) = ?$ What can you say about the distribution of the sum of three normal random variables? Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment continued:* Simulation suggesting approximate answers below (accurate to about 2 places). You should get exact answers
using normal tables or software.

```
set.seed(827)
m = 10^6;  n = 3
x = rnorm(m*n);  DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)
t = rowSums(DTA)
mean(t > 0);  mean(t > 1);  mean(t > 3)
[1] 0.500548
[1] 0.282697
[1] 0.041659
```

[image]